# unable to access session using next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

[image]

The session is stored in cookies. When I use this `` {session ? `${session.user.email}` : ''} `` it keeps saying undefined.

This is my JSON object:

```json
{
        "user": {
            "token": {
                "responseCode": 0,
                "responseMessage": "success",
                "data": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "userId": "SYS-9d502c43-9ef3-432d-ab93-be0b8236cdff",
                    "fullName": "yeshewas string",
                    "username": "yes@yes.com",
                    "userRole": "Super User",
                    "permissions": []
                }
            }
        },
        "expires": "2022-06-24T06:14:39.011Z"
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the `[...nextauth].js` callbacks?

Comment: i have added the screenshot above

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `jwt` callback like this:

```
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      user && (token.user = user.user)

      return token;
    },
  },
```